# Маршрутизация пакетов

Tags: ubuntu, маршрутизация

Есть четыре машины с ubuntu server 14.04. Пытаюсь настроить передачу пакетов через все 4 машины.

Конфигурация первой машины :

```
eth1 ip - 192.168.11.2 netmask - 255.255.255.0
```

Маршруты :

```
Dest           Gateway       Genmask         Iface 
192.168.11.0   *             255.255.255.0   eth1
192.168.13.0   191.168.11.3  255.255.255.0   eth1
```

Конфигурация второй машины :

```
eth0 ip - 192.168.11.3 netmask - 255.255.255.0
eth1 ip - 192.168.12.4 netmask - 255.255.255.0
```

Маршруты :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конфигурация третьей машины :

```
eth1 ip - 192.168.12.5 netmask - 255.255.255.0
eth0 ip - 192.168.13.6 netmask - 255.255.255.0
```

Маршруты :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конфигурация четвертой машины :

```
eth1 ip - 192.168.13.7 netmask - 255.255.255.0
```

Маршруты :

```
Dest           Gateway       Genmask         Iface 
192.168.13.0   *             255.255.255.0   eth1
```

Не получается передать пакеты с машины 1 на машину 4(на адрес 192.168.13.7), если судить по данным выводимым tcpdump в последний раз передаваемые пакеты появляются на машине 3(192.168.12.5), хотя если попробовать провести передачу с машины 2 на машину 4 все получается. В чем ошибка, подскажите?

Comment: На 4й машине это единственная запись маршрутизации ? Или на ней есть еще default ? Судя по приведенной маршрутизации она просто не знает, где находятся НЕ 13 подсети. Хотя это должно ей так же мешать работать и со второй машиной

Comment: И первая машина не знает где находится 12 подсеть, если чо

Comment: @Mike , на 4 машине это единственная запись. Пока преследую цель передачи с 1 машины на 4, с 4 машины передавать я ничего не буду.

Comment: Все машины должны знать о всех подсетях. Добавьте на ней хотя бы запись `route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.13.6` или какой там ip у предыдущей машины. ну или вообще `route add default ...` что бы она все пакеты которые явно не знает куда девать отправляла на ее маршрутизатор

Comment: @Mike , действительно надо было просто указать пути в другие сети. Спасибо большое.